# Which class files i still need on the classpath after aspectJ compile time weaving?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Let's say i have an app built from 3 files:

`MyApp.java` (application):

```
public class MyApp {...}
```

`MyAspect.aj` (adds some functionality to the app):

```
public aspect MyAspect {

   before(): execution(* MyApp.*(..)) {
     AspectHelper helper = new AspectHelper()
     ...
   }
}
```

`AspectHelper.java` (used ONLY by the aspect)

```
class AspectHelper {...}
```

after a compile time weaving i'll have `MyApp.class`, `MyAspect.class`, `AspectHelper.class`. when i run the app, do i need all 3 files on the classpath or some of them will be built in the `MyApp.class` bytecode and i don't need them as a separate files anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your weaved classes (`MyApp`) will reference the aspect class (`MyAspect`). The code you wrote in your aspect class will reference your helper class (`AspectHelper`). You will need all files. And of course, the aspectj runtime too. You can check the compiled code with a decompiler tool or with `javap`. Try with `javap -p -c -s MyApp.class` on your compiled classes directory.